# Android Studio - ADB is not responding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I just installed Android Studio, and it seems to import and convert my projects well.

However, whenever I try to run a project, I get the error back that adb is not responding and I should kill it. **This is the case even afer a fresh computer restart.**

I can launch: Tool - Android - AVD manager

Could it be a 32bit versus 64bit issue? Or something odd like that? Seeing a complete restart did not solve the problem, I am not sure how to solve this. I also can not see adb running in Windows task manager nor in Windows services.

Comment: I suggest confirming that it works from command line first (eg. `adb devices`), if not enable `trace error` (check adb man page (or however that's called on Windows ;)))

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a 64-bit OS, Android Studio will prompt you to use its 64-bit version. You'll also be needing  to install a 64-bit JDK. If you're using an Android SDK bundle from Eclipse, it's best to update your SDK library.

Comment: I use 64bit OS - but JDK is 64bit and I downloaded entirely new SDK library for Android Studio